# redirect url with pattern in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have a magento site where I am redirecting some urls to new urls in htaccess

olds urls is like this `domain.com/dinnerware-24.html` and its number is **From 1 to 99** and it is dynamic
now i want create pattern if my url have number, delete it automaticly and redirect to new url e.g

```
domain.com/dinnerware-25?q=1 or domain.com/dinnerware-99.html
```

**redirect to** `domain.com/dinnerware?q=1 and domain.com/dinnerware.html`

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have duplicate url's. In some older Magento versions this behaviour is also buggy and leads to urls with new increments after each reindex.

A solution would be to delete values of "url_path" attribute from catalog_product_entity_varchar table, truncate core_url_rewrite table and do a fresh reindex

You may consider to manually add some unique suffixes to your products or categories "name" or "url_key" attribute, to avoid this behaviour in the first place.

There is also a downside of deleting old redirects. From SEO point of view you may lose linkjuice that was distributed from old urls